# Redux Store updating but no updated state in mapStateToProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a redux store which I am updating from a service. An action is dispatched. The store.getState() is returning the updated state but on mapStateToProps() the initial state is showing up.

Have tried reading the docs which describe troubleshooting, but no luck. I am adding code samples in which I am stuck.

Troubleshooting guides at the respective and some questions on SO. 
https://react-redux.js.org/troubleshooting 
https://redux.js.org/troubleshooting

I am using Ignite2(https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) which has a boilerplate as following

```
//index.js for reducers
//EDIT:
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import configureStore from './CreateStore'
import rootSaga from '../Sagas/'

/* ------------- Assemble The Reducers ------------- */
export const reducers = combineReducers({
  search: require('./SearchRedux').reducer,
  playerStateReducer: require('./PlayerStateReducer'),
})

export default () => {
  let { store, sagasManager, sagaMiddleware } = configureStore(reducers, rootSaga)
 return store
}
```

```
//service.js 
//using react-native-track-player
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('playback-state', (data) => {

module.exports = async function(store, data) {
TrackPlayer.addEventListener('playback-state', (data) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PLAYER_STATE', currentState: data.state })
    console.log(store.getState(), data, "store and data")
//gives me updated state from store
})
}
```

```
//PlayerStateReducer.js

export const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    if (action.type == 'UPDATE_PLAYER_STATE') {
        return action.currentState 
    } else {
        return state
    }
}
```

```
//PlayerUI.js
...
...
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.playerStateReducer, "player state")
    //This gives me the initial state i.e. 0 
    return {
        playerState: state.playerStateReducer
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlayerUI)
```

I am a newbie in React Native development. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

There is no need for `.reducer`

```
import playerStateReducer from './PlayerStateReducer';

export const reducers = combineReducers({
  playerStateReducer,
});
```

**Issue 2**

Since your're going to exec an async action inside your redux action ... you need to wire `redux-thunk` middleware to your redux store ... and do something like this

```
module.exports = (yourActionParam1, yourActionParam2) => async(dispatch) => {
    const payload = await someAsyncOp();
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PLAYER_STATE', payload });
};
```

Comment: Tried this. But No success

Comment: Edit to the above code(s) has been made. Please have a look.

Comment: You have a problem in your service.js file .... your action has to be defined directly in a separate file like the example action in my answer

Comment: Secondly, your redux store is **ready** to give you the initial state when you map it to your component ... and you don't have to call a specific action to return the intial state ... you need only to call an action  to **return a new value**

Comment: Thanks for giving steps towards a solution. I am proceeding with what you said and as soon as I have implemented will post the same or any problem. Many thanks.